# Database for tracking the statuses of documents inside a documents management system

Tags: java, database, logging, nosql

I'm starting to build a record keeping database for the documents we manage on our system. Each document goes through a bunch of specific processing tasks that I will call here **normalization**, **conversion** and **extraction**.

The document processing may fail at any of these steps, so, I'm looking for a solution where i can quickly store this information for archiving but I should also be able to query the information (and possibly summarize it). If I would define my data structure in json it would possibly look like this:

```
{ 10123 : [
    { queue : 'converter',
      startedAt : 'date-here',
      finishedAt: 'date-here',
      error : { message : 'error message', stackTrace : 'stack trace here' },
      machine : '192.168.0.1'
    } , 
    { queue : 'extractor',
      startedAt : 'date-here',
      finishedAt: 'date-here',
      error : { message : 'error message', stackTrace : 'stack trace here' },
      machine : '192.168.0.1'
    }, 
    { queue : 'extractor',
      startedAt : 'date-here',
      finishedAt: 'date-here',
      error : { message : 'error message', stackTrace : 'stack trace here' },
      machine : '192.168.0.1'
    }, 
] }
```

In an ideal world I would have the full processing life information from a specific document and should also be able to detect wich ones have failed and the average time each process takes.

Any hints on an ideal database solution to handle this? This would possibly go for a couple of thousands writes a day.

The main solution is written in Java, so the DB should have a Java driver.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're marking this "nosql?" This seems like a task that could be accomplished with about three tables in SQL.

Comment: Relational databases are usually bad in write-intensive solutions, but I may also give it a try using a real SQL db is none o the NoSQL solutions are usable.

Comment: With a couple of thousand writes per day, you have 43s for each write. Is there some other activity that makes you call it "write-heavy"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mongodb](http://www.mongodb.org/) is a right choice for this since it supports all your expected features out of the box

- documents/embedded documents
- json compatible
- support querying (of course except joins)
- super fast
- java driver supported by 10gen

check out [mongodb use cases](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Use+Cases) for more info